# Возникает ошибка "django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "shopapp_order" already exists" при запуске теста

Tags: python, django

При запуске теста `python manage.py test shopapp.tests.AddTwoNumbersTestCase` возникает ошибка

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: table "shopapp_order" already exists

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться почему?

`utils.py`:

```
def add_two_numbers(a, b):
    return a + b
```

`tests.py`:

```
class AddTwoNumbersTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_add_two_numbers(self):
        result = add_two_numbers(2, 3)
        self.assertEqual(result, 5)
```